# Translating "All things come to an end" to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

Would someone please translate "All things come to an end" for me?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Was there any special meaning you wanted to convey with this statement, or were you looking for a very literal translation?

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of it in the "this too shall pass" concept. The idea that whether good or bad, everything is only temporary. Let me know if that makes sense!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is Seneca's.

> Nihil perpetuum, pauca diuturna sunt; aliud alio modo fragile est, rerum exitus variantur, ceterum **quicquid coepit et desinit.**

> Nothing lasts forever, few things even last for long: all are susceptible of decay in one way or another; moreover **all that begins also ends.** (Wiki quotes translation).

The bold part ("*Quicquid coepit et desinit*") literally means as in the English translation "whatever/all that begins also ends/stops" which is not literal translation of "all things come to an end" but I think it is an attractive option to convey the same.

One can also chose the first two words: **Nihil perpetuum** which render the required on the negative

Comment: Thank you! That is a great explanation.

Comment: @Lilith This is indeed a good answer, but I hope you will allow time for more answers, too. Often we get several good answers to this kind of question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that d_e's Seneca quote is perfect. But going on the assumption that more is better and encouraged by Ben Kovitz's comment, I'll go ahead and add to the quantity (if not the quality) of responses with a quote from the Vulgate, 2 Cor 4:18.

*Quae enim videntur temporalia sunt*, for things that are seen are temporary.

The verse goes on to say, *Quae autem non videntur aeterna sunt*, but things which are not seen are eternal.